# Can't add component to vue apps template - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components, vue-component

I've added a main vue app in my application. And I want to add a component to the app.

Trying to add TopMenu.vue to the App.vue:

`<top-menu></top-menu>` in App.vue.

Registered in main.js for app.
Am I using the single file components correct?

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/App'
import TopMenu from './components/TopMenu'

Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  components: {
    'top-menu': TopMenu
  }
})
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <top-menu></top-menu>
    <div class="container drop-shadow">
      <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
      <p1>{{ about }}</p1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Hello kosken!",
      about: "Using Parcel In A Vue.js App"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

TopMenu.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="user-menu drop-shadow"></div>
</template> 

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'top-menu',
        data: function () {
            return "somedata";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import it and use it inside your `App.vue` :

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <top-menu></top-menu>
    <div class="container drop-shadow">
      <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
      <p1>{{ about }}</p1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TopMenu from './TopMenu'
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Hello kosken!",
      about: "Using Parcel In A Vue.js App"
    };
  },  
  components: {
    'top-menu': TopMenu
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/App'
import TopMenu from './components/TopMenu'

Vue.component('top-menu', TopMenu)
```

This is how you should register component globally and you can use it anywhere.